# Executing CREATE VIEW & ALTER VIEW from SQLCMD

Tags: t-sql, sqlcmd

I'm trying to execute a sql file with the following contents using sql cmd.

```
sqlcmd -S localhost\dbInstance -i Sample.sql -v  filepath="C:\Sql\"
```

***Sample.sql contents:***

```
USE Sample_db
GO
BEGIN
 BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
  BEGIN TRY
   CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Test_View]
   AS SELECT * from Sample_table;   

   ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Sample_View]   
   AS SELECT * FROM table_9;        

   ALTER TABLE [Sample_Table_2] ADD Col_4 VARCHAR(20);

  END TRY 
 BEGIN CATCH     
  SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber         ,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity         ,
    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState         ,
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure         ,
    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine         ,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;     

  IF @@TRANCOUNT &gt; 0         
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 

 END CATCH;

 IF @@TRANCOUNT &gt; 0     
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END  
GO
```

***When I execute the sqlcmd, it throws the following error:***

```
C:\Sql&gt;sqlcmd -S localhost\dbInstance -i Sample.sql -v  filepath="C:\Sql\"
Changed database context to 'Sample_db'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server localhost\dbInstance, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'.
```

***Question:***
Why am I not able to create view and alter view from sqlcmd, while I'm able to alter table?
When I comment out the CREATE VIEW and ALTER VIEW statement, the script executed fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As per the manual:

> The CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in a query batch.

Although, to tell the truth, that statement is rather misleading, because in actual fact `CREATE VIEW` must be the **only** statement in the batch, as you can ascertain for yourself from this illustration of a very simple test:

[image: CREATE VIEW issue illustration]

The error message in the *Messages* pane says `Incorrect syntax near keyword 'SELECT'`, but if you hover over the underscored `CREATE VIEW` statement, a hint message appears that reveals that you can't put anything neither before `CREATE VIEW` nor after its `SELECT` statement.

And it's precisely the same issue with `ALTER VIEW`.

So, you *can* have a `CREATE VIEW` and/or an `ALTER VIEW` statement(s) perform within a transaction (by delimiting them with `GO` keywords), but you will not be able to use `BEGIN TRY ... BEGIN CATCH` to catch exceptions raised by those statements.

Unless, as Aaron Bertrand correctly reminds me, you execute those statements as dynamic queries, using either `EXEC(…)` or `EXEC sp_executesql …`, something like this, perhaps:

```
…
 BEGIN TRY
   EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Test_View]
   AS SELECT * from Sample_table';   

   EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER VIEW [dbo].[Sample_View]   
   AS SELECT * FROM table_9';        

   ALTER TABLE [Sample_Table_2] ADD Col_4 VARCHAR(20);

 END TRY 
 BEGIN CATCH     
…
```

Comment: ...unless you enclose the DDL in dynamic SQL.