# T-SQL: ALTER VIEW error within a transaction and try-catch block

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, alter

I am using SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express. I have a script with below scheme:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO

BEGIN TRY
    ALTER VIEW dbo.MyView
    AS
    SELECT ...
    GO
    ALTER TABLE ...
    GO
    UPDATE dbo.MyTable ...
    GO
    INSERT INTO dbo.AnotherTable ...
    GO
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

The problem is that I am receiving the error in the ALTER VIEW dbo.MyView block:
"Incorrect syntax near reserved word 'VIEW'."

Comment: Alter View must be the only statement in the batch. It can't be in there. See explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466261/executing-create-view-alter-view-from-sqlcmd

Comment: @sanmis Well, it seems it is possible using "ALTER VIEW" statements as dynamic queries, using either EXEC(…) or EXEC sp_executesql. as explained at the end of the post you mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466261/executing-create-view-alter-view-from-sqlcmd But my problem now is that when enclosing my alter view as EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER VIEW...'; another different error appears: "Incorrect syntax near ';'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This didn't give me any syntax error, try this. I just removed "Go" at the end of dynamic sql.

```
USE [MyDatabase]
go
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
go
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go
BEGIN TRANSACTION
go
BEGIN TRY
EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER VIEW dbo.MyView
AS
SELECT * FROM ....; '
EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER TABLE ...;'
EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE ....;'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Comment: You are right. The problem was in the GO statements within BEGIN TRY-END TRY block. Removing them now it works. A lot of thanks!